# Transform into product: $\sin (3x)- \cos x - \sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone give an idea (an idea to start) about how to transform in product the following expression:
$$\sin(3x)-\cos(x)-\sin(x)$$
Mention that I tried to write $\sin(3x)$ as $\sin(2x+x)$, or $\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2 + x)$ but I go back to the initial expression or it gets very complicated .
Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think that this can be transformed into a product? I doubt it very much.

Comment: I agree with @Somos. Do you have any reason to believe that?

Comment: $\sin (3\theta)= 3 \sin (\theta)−4\sin (3\theta )$, so the expression becomes
$$ 3 \sin (\theta)−4\sin ^3(\theta ) - \sin \theta - \cos \theta$$

Comment: I found this exercise in a book.  A few days ago I tried 4 hours trying various formulas, so there are two possibilities: you can use a trick calculation or is a misprint. But the exercise was like this: $$sin(\frac{9a}{4})-cos(\frac{3a}{4})-sin(\frac{3a}{4}),$$ and I noted $x=\frac{3x}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

I am agree totally with the user @Somos, because

$$\sin(3x)-\cos(x)-\sin(x) \iff \sin(3x)-(\cos(x)+\sin(x))$$
But
$$\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\sqrt2 \sin (x+\varphi)$$
(added angle method).

Hence
$$\sin(3x)-\cos(x)-\sin(x) \iff \sin(3x)-\sqrt2 \sin (x+\varphi)$$
and you can not apply the prostapheresis formulas for the presence of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: If it was $+\sin(x)$ at the end I see how it might factor. $\sin(a) + \sin(b) = 2 \sin(\frac{a+b}{2}) \cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$ means that $\sin(3x) + \sin(x) = 2 \sin(2x) \cos(x)$ so if you subtract off a $\cos(x)$ you do get a nice product, $(2 \sin(2x) - 1) \cos(x)$.

Comment: @leslietownes You are absolutely right, I approve of your comment and I also vote for more of your answers :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano, I applied this technique as well, and I came to the same result. But without any result in being able to give common factor.

Comment: @leslietownes Thanks for your response, I thought about this too, but I thought that if a product can be formed and I give up so easily.

Comment: @MarkBen Hi, in fact you not can factorized with the same angle $x=3a/4$.

Comment: @Sebastiano why not? It is just a notation to simplify calculations.

Comment: @MarkBen The problem that you can not factorize it is on the two parts $-\cos(x)-\sin(x)$. In fact you in the total expression you can not use prostapheresis formulas. If there was $1$ instead of $\sqrt 2$ then all it is ok. See also the first comment of my answer.

Comment: Oh..there was confusion in my head. I was thinking of something completely different about exercise. But yes, you're right $\sqrt{2}$ don't allow using prosthaphaeresis formulas. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarkBen Don't worry absolutely. I often am very tired.